# gcc Error: unrecognized option `--out-implib'

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to run these gcc commands on Windows 10 and facing this error.

`gcc version egcs-2.91.57 19980901 (egcs-1.1 release)`

No error during compilation

```
g++ -c -DBUILD_MY_DLL shared_lib.cpp
```

Error while creating dll

```
g++ -shared -o shared_lib.dll shared_lib.o -Wl,--out-implib,libshared_lib.a
```

Error:

```
g++: unrecognized option `-shared'
/cygnus/cygwin-b20/H-i586-cygwin32/i586-cygwin32/bin/ld: unrecognized option `--out-implib'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I reomove `-shared` from the start then the other two errors are still there.

```
/cygnus/cygwin-b20/H-i586-cygwin32/i586-cygwin32/bin/ld: unrecognized option `--out-implib'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**shared_lib.h**

```
#ifndef SHARED_LIB_H
#define SHARED_LIB_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef BUILD_MY_DLL
    #define SHARED_LIB __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define SHARED_LIB __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

int SHARED_LIB Add(int a, int b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif

#endif // end dll
```

**shared_lib.cpp**

```
#include "shared_lib.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


int SHARED_LIB Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: What GCC distribution is this?